# Создание сущности и загрузка файлов на сервер

Tags: java, spring, rest, архитектура

Работаю рест эндпоинтом для создания сущности контракта с помощью spring-экосистемы. Сущность предполагает возможность прикрепить сканы документов. Возник вопрос как лучше выполнить запрос на создание:

- одним запросом, т.е. сразу прикрепить файлы к данным сущности
- или поэтапно сначала создать сущность, а потом отправить файлы отдельным запросом

Какой подход выбрать? Какие ньюансы есть у каждого из способов?

Comment: То есть, целевой запрос – отправка сканов? И вопрос в том, надо ли отправку и создание контактов делать сразу там же или отдельно и предварительно?

Comment: целевой запрос - создание сушности контракта, частью сущности являются сканы

Answer (score 1):

Наиболее универсальный (использую много лет в ECMS) такой вариант:

1. Сначала клиент просит сервер сгенерировать ему URI для загрузки содержимого файла в хранилище типа (AWS S3 или Azure Blob Storage). У этого URI есть срок жизни, т.е. он дает право, скажем, в течении 10 минут загрузить файл. Так же вместе с этим URI может передаваться идентификатор содержимого сгенерированного сервером (назовем его `blob_id`).
2. Клиент загружает содержимое по этому URI в хранилище.
3. Клиент создает контракт через API сервера, при этом он указывает ссылку на содержимое (`blob_id`).
4. Регулярно запускается процедура, которая удаляет загруженные файлы, для которых так и не были созданы контракты.

Эта схема позволяет:

1. создавать контракты атомарно, т.е. не будет контрактов без файлов, которые по сути не должны существовать по бизнес правилам.
2. разгружает сервер, т.к. загрузка файлов идет напрямую в хранилище. Не нужно временное хранилище на сервере и т.д.

Плата - это усложнение логики и необходимость поддерживать еще процедуру очистки.