# Где хранить текст?

Tags: c#

В приложении имеется сущность "Статья" у статьи есть название и текст. Вот тут у меня возник вопрос, можно ли хранить большой текст в БД? Под большим я имею ввиду 10000-30000 символов. Или есть какие-то другие способы? Приложение на ASP.NET Core. Я подумывал выгружать его куда-то, а в БД сохранять ссылку. Но как это реализовать?)

Comment: а почему напрямую не в бд? По каких именно причинах от идеи записи в бд отказываешся?

Comment: 30000 символов - это очень мало. Можно хранить в БД.

Comment: Какая бд у вас?

Comment: @tym32167, postgres

Comment: @aepot, хорошо, а если 100000 - 500000. Вот например)

Comment: У вашей был нет лимита на размер записи? Или может вы файл прямо в бд хранить можете?

Comment: @tym32167, в postgres файлы сохранять можно, но это может сказаться на скорости, да памяти будет много занимать. Я подумал, а что если формировать файлы, а в БД тупа сохранять к ним путь

Comment: я предлагаю не заниматься фигней а просто реализовать все через базу данных. А когда возникнут проблемы - тогда уже задумываться как их обойти. Потому что сейчас ты страдаешь хренью, прости на слове.

Comment: Можно хранить файл и вне БД, а в БД только ссылку. Только это сразу куча неочевидных и нетривиальных проблем. Начиная с атомарности создания такого файла (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1194354/218971). В общем, не рекомендую, если на то нет причин. Память, что там что тут будет занимать.

Comment: Смотрите документацию вашей бд. Никакие файлы бд замедлить не должны. Другое дело, если вы эти файлы часто и по многу считывать собрались, то это может повлиять на канал передачи данных. Но такой нагрузкой не каждый сайт может похвастаться.

Comment: @tym32167, я так подумал рил буду тупа сохранять текст в БД)

Comment: [To BLOB or Not To BLOB](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/to-blob-or-not-to-blob-large-object-storage-in-a-database-or-a-filesystem/). Хранение файлов в БД выгоднее до размеров примерно 256 кб, от мегабайта и выше - в файловой системе. Наибольшее влияние оказывает фрагментация. | Ах, да, это справедливо для HDD. | А ещё всё зависит от СУБД и от файловой системы. Короче, сделайте хоть как-то для начала.

Comment: Это же научное исследование :) Оно проводилось для фиксированного набора операций сравнивая конкретную версию MSSQL с конкретной версией NTFS для разных размеров файлов. Что будет для postgresql и другой FS, да еще если учесть кучу других факторов - неизвестно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Хранить файлы в БД или файловой системе? - этим вопросом задаются на протяжении многих лет. И неоднократно делались разные тесты на эту тему.

[To BLOB or Not To BLOB: Large Object Storage in a Database or a Filesystem](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/to-blob-or-not-to-blob-large-object-storage-in-a-database-or-a-filesystem/) - можно ознакомиться с одним из них.

Кратко: Хранение файлов в БД выгоднее до размеров примерно 256 кб, от мегабайта и выше - в файловой системе. Наибольшее влияние оказывает фрагментация. Кроме того, соединение с БД уже установлено, а файл ещё нужно открыть - на это тоже уходит время.

Тестирование проводилось на HDD, OS Windows, файловая система NTFS, Sql Server.

На SSD результаты могут существенно отличаться, т. к. фрагментирование влияет намного меньше.
На другой ОС, а вернее, на другой файловой системе результат тоже может быть другим.
Естественно, многое зависит от движка базы данных.

Кроме того, в некоторых СУБД есть специфические возможности. Например, в Sql Server есть [FILESTREAM](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/blob/filestream-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15). Работаете с этим типом, как с обычной колонкой, а файл будет храниться не в таблице, а в файловой системе. При этом сохраняются все удобства СУБД: транзакционная целостность и т. п.

Answer (score 0):

Делайте в БД, будут проблемы - выносите из БД, тестируйте, сравнивайте.