# Влияют ли повторяющиеся строки на размер базы данных?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

К примеру если рассмотреть такую таблицу в postgresql

```
create table employee (
id BIGSERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
first_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
last_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
country_of_birth VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);
```

Получается у каждого работника будет прописана страна из которой он.
Есть ли смысл создавать отдельную таблицу со странами, а в таблице работника в поле **country_of_birth** подставлять только **country_id**, или здесь не будет выигрыша в суммарном объеме памяти занимаемой базой данных? То есть у нас в базе данных не будет 1000 строк **"Russia"**, а будет 1000 int'ов. Или может postgresql сам оптимизирует одинаковые строки?

```
create table country (
id BIGSERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: Отдельную таблицу тут имеет смысл вводить скорее как защиту от опечаток. Что бы у вас не было стран Russia, Rusia, Russai и т.п.

Comment: Это просто пример, в реалиях будут строки 20-40 символов, которые будут постоянно повторяться в таблице и не понятно выиграю ли я если вынесу их в отдельную таблицу.

Comment: в любом учебнике по СУБД откройте главу про нормализацию данных и читайте. БД бы вам оптимизировала, если бы там был enum как в mysql (хз как оно в postgre). а так да, будет избыточный объем, будет более медленый поиск, будут лишние движения по выборке списка стран, не будет контроля целостности, каскадных обновления и удалений

Comment: @teran после прочтения комментария я еще больше запутался. В каком случае будет избыточный объем и более медленный поиск? Когда все в одном или когда отдельные таблицы?

Comment: когда все в одном

Comment: @teran А подскажи по другому вопросу, к примеру каждому элементу в таблице соответствует словарь json (300-500кб) по которому не нужно делать поиск или анализ. Как лучше всего его сохранить? Сделать дополнительное поле в таблице под него? Или просто разместить в файловой системе, а путь указать опять таки в дополнительном поле в таблице?

Comment: Лучше в БД хранить. Если хранить в файловой системе, то нужно будет разруливать неприятные проблемы с атомарностью и целостностью.

Comment: Хранить ли файл (json) в колонке или в файловой системе: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1306445/184217